# Json request object is undefined

Tags: javascript, json

So im trying to get a json request from the open weather api example. But for some reason when i go to call the key value in the $.each method it says that the value for the key is undefined. Could you guys take a look at the code and see what it is im missing?

```js
function getGs(data) {
  $.each(data.main,function(i,wather){
    console.log(weather.humidity);
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var bggAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139?";

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: bggAPI
  });
  
  getGs();
  
});
```

Comment: `getGs();` call is not getting any data passed

Comment: all that is though is to call the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` does an async request.
Once it is successfully completed, `success` is triggered and you missed it.
`data.main` is not an array, but an object.
`data.weather` is an array.

```js
function getGs(data) {
  console.log(data.main.humidity);
  $.each(data.weather,function(i, weather) {
    console.log(weather.main);
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var bggAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139?";

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: bggAPI,
    success:getGs
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The object is not `data.main` but `data.weather.main` instead.

Comment: I am sorry to disagree, but yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple you have a typo.

You are using `wather` as parameter but calling `weather` inside your function.

**Edit:**

In your given json :

```
{ coord: { lon: 138.93, lat: 34.97 }, weather: [ { id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "Sky is Clear", icon: "01n" } ], base: "cmc stations", main: { temp: 300.37, pressure: 1015, humidity: 82, temp_min: 300.37, temp_max: 300.37 }, wind: { speed: 0.51, deg: 314, gust: 1.03 }, clouds: { all: 0 }, dt: 1438897427, sys: { type: 3, id: 10294, message: 0.0102, country: "JP", sunrise: 1438804655, sunset: 1438854132 }, id: 1851632, name: "Shuzenji", cod: 200 }
```

you have a `weather` array but you are looping through main asvarray while it's only a property inside the weather array, your code should be:

```
$.each(data.weather,function(i,weather){
  console.log(weather.main);
  })
}
```

Comment: i fixed that and still the same thing

Comment: its saying main is undfined

Comment: Please post the json structure are you sure there is `main` inside it?

Comment: {
coord: {
lon: 138.93,
lat: 34.97
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "Sky is Clear",
icon: "01n"
}
],
base: "cmc stations",
main: {
temp: 300.37,
pressure: 1015,
humidity: 82,
temp_min: 300.37,
temp_max: 300.37
},
wind: {
speed: 0.51,
deg: 314,
gust: 1.03
},
clouds: {
all: 0
},
dt: 1438897427,
sys: {
type: 3,
id: 10294,
message: 0.0102,
country: "JP",
sunrise: 1438804655,
sunset: 1438854132
},
id: 1851632,
name: "Shuzenji",
cod: 200
}

Comment: 'humidity' isn't in the 'weather' array. it is in the 'main' object

Comment: Thank you i have know idea why i didn't see that before still new to every thing so i really have to pay more attention to that but thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @AlexGwartney you are welcome, if it helps you please accept/vote it my answer.

Comment: just did sorry for got to do it earlyer